# Generate points along branching lines

Tags: point, line, topology, network

I am looking to generate points along a series of connected lines at regular intervals, but I wish to keep this interval even when a line is branching into 2 or 3 other lines. All the regular tools I tested in ArcMap or QGIS generate points on a feature basis meaning that the interval restart at each node.

On the picture I drew road network (blue lines), direction flow (orange arrows) and desired points (red dots). The first point is at 50m from the beginning of the first line, then a second 50m further but then there is a node within the next 50m. The usual tools would then start "fresh" on the two branches but I want to keep the 50m distance between the last point before the node and the first point on each branch. How could this be done? I suppose some topology may be needed...

[image: Desired points along lines]

I am looking for a free solution, ideally with Python, QGIS, SAGA, GRASS, GDAL or alike. In last resort, I could use ArcMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate distance to outlet (using network analyst, maybe. I used networkx) for every node:

[image]

Transfer this info into links table:

[image]

Create routes - linear referencing:

```
arcpy.CreateRoutes_lr(in_line_features="LINKS", route_id_field="Route", out_feature_class="C:/SCRATCH/SCRATCH.gdb/ROUTES", measure_source="TWO_FIELDS", from_measure_field="From_T", to_measure_field="To_T", coordinate_priority="UPPER_LEFT", measure_factor="1", measure_offset="0", ignore_gaps="IGNORE", build_index="INDEX")
```

Note fields I used in above (!).

Create table like that in Excel to cover longest segment:

[image]

Add text field aLink to Routes, populate it by "A" and index that field.
Use create query table to multiply records from Excel table:

```
arcpy.MakeQueryTable_management(in_table="ROUTES;fromExcel", out_table="QueryTable3", in_key_field_option="ADD_VIRTUAL_KEY_FIELD", in_key_field="", in_field="", where_clause="ROUTES.aLink = fromExcel.R")
```

and create event layer using Routes and extended table:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was able to do a similar thing with arcgis pro's network analyst. Using the "service area" feature, I set it to create lines (instead of the default polygons) and accumulate distance at the start/end points. I had to manually enter my list of breaks (10,20,...,200,210,...500,) as there is no "every X unit" ability. This created the lines in a feature class, and I could use the "vertex to points" tool to change the ending vertex of each line into a point.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [v.to.points](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/v.to.points.html) (this will create points at a specified distance along your input lines in new vector map)

Note that the distance between generated points will be in map units.

Comment: It is not ArcGis (a) and how does it handle branching issue (b) ?

Comment: I just tested GRASS v.to.points but it doesn't handle branching nor does it use a regular interval on all features, only within each feature.