# Buffering line segments that intersect another segment using a specific field value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, buffer

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.2 with an Advanced level license.

I have a field (Fish) that scribes whether a stream has fish (dark blue - 100 ft buffer) or no fish(light blue- 35 ft buffer for 500ft upstream of fish stream). I'd like to buffer nonfish streams that touch a fish stream for 500 feet with a different buffer value. Currently I am visually finding nonfish streams, measuring 500 ft from the fish stream, splitting the stream at that point, updating the buffer field of that newly split segment, and finally running the buffer on the layer.

[image]

This is very time consuming.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: What software do you have available to do this? I take it that 500 feet up the stream you want to calculate linear distance following the stream and not *as the crow flies*, is this correct?

Comment: ArcGIS Pro. Yes following the stream would be ideal.

Comment: There is an interactive tool that will split lines based on length https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-existing-features/splitting-lines-at-a-specified-distance-or-percentage.htm but you need to know if the distance is from the start or the end.

Comment: If you have an advanced license you can export your 'has fish' end points and a selection of your 'no fish' that touches (from and to separate), perform a near from both 'no fish' endpoints to the 'has fish' endpoints, join by attribute the tables from 'no fish' to both end points then select the ones that have near_dist in the join where to point is less than from point, these ones split from their to point, then do that again for the alternate case. Hopefully the split tool accepts multiple selection.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I will give those a try and see where I can get!

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316135/generate-points-along-branching-lines#316198

Answer (score 1):

RivEX for ArcPro has the [Nearby upstream network tool](https://www.rivex.co.uk/RivEX-Manual/Createupstreamnearbynetwork.html#Limitations) that will fully automate this processing.

In the example I show below the snapped red points from the "fish river" are fed into the nearby network tool with an appropriate search distance and the optional processing step of creating a buffer is selected.  The output are the green polylines and the hatched buffer.  It would then be up to you to dissolve your large buffer with the smaller buffer.

[image: Example of output]